# Animating right to left issue in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

As you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/poxgawf4/ , it is working the direction left- right. I want to do exactly the opposite; from right - left.
How can I do that ? thx

```
$(".inno-bg").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
        'marginTop': "-=60px"
    }, 200);
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
    $(this).css("background-color", "#1A6397");
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ width: "320px" });
    $(this).find("p").fadeIn( 1000 );
});

$(".inno-bg").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=60px"
    }, 200);
    imageUrl = "http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2014/02/gaia_calibration_image/14263603-2-eng-GB/Gaia_calibration_image_node_full_image_2.jpg";
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({ width: "160px" });
    $(this).find("p").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When animating anything from right to left, you need to position it absolutely within its container. This is because by default elements are keyed to the top left, which needs changing to the top right. Try this, note that I've only included the properties I changed/added here:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.inno-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/poxgawf4/1/)

Comment: thx a lot , if you have any better suggestion to the jquery part, to improve it, please let me know :)